# Yarn MRV2 performance Tuning Number of mappers and Reducers MRV1 performance better

Tags: hadoop, jar, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, mapr

I'm running MR java program with Yarn , even though Number of mappers are 24 , but actual running mappers are 10 , the remaining 14 maps are in pending state. how to make them also to running mode . we are running MAPR 6 node cluster .
changed the below properties in mapred-site.xml and Yarn-site.xml .
these values are overridden from the default values , still I'm not seeing any perfomance Bench mark .

Note . I'm running same Program with MRv1 performance wise it's better some how . So please suggest me how to utilize the cluster utilization resources well .

command Used :
***yarn jar /opt/cluster/bin/logmessage-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.message.WordPreprocessDriver -Dmapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize=33554432 /data/123.txt***

In yarn-site

```
<name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
<value>20960</value>
<name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>
<value>2048</value>
```

In mapred-site

```
<name>mapreduce.map.memory.mb</name>
<value>4096</value>
<name>mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb</name>
<value>8192</value>
<name>mapreduce.map.java.opts</name>
<value>-Xmx3072m</value>
<name>mapreduce.reduce.java.opts</name>
<value>-Xmx6144m</value>
```

mapreduce.job.maps

```
<name> mapreduce.job.maps</name>
<value>4</value>
```

You see 
Actually the total  containers were running as 11 . there was 40 vcores were available, among them 11 vcores were used while running MR program .  can you please share what properties needs to change for that .?

[image]

Thank you ,
Madhu

Comment: What are the overall resource configuration for YARN? Has each of the workers 20 GB of memory? What about `yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores` settings?

Comment: Yes each worker has 25 GB of memory . and yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores are 8 . Should we over rides this vocres too ?

Comment: In the YARN Resource Manager Web UI you should see the number of containers allocated at each worker. Could you post a screenshot? There may be a problem because 10 mappers are definitely not balanced across 6 workers equally.

Comment: You see the image ? Actually the total containers were running as 11 . there was 40 vcores were available, among them 11 vcores were used while running MR program . can you please share what properties needs to change for that .?

Comment: @vanekjar can you please suggest me If you have any thoughts for this ?

Comment: Actually I don't know the solution right now. It makes more sense with the screenshot (10 map tasks running on 5 workers), but I don't know why each of the workers runs just two tasks. Maybe some default hidden somewhere, but really don't know. Hopefully someone else will know.